# How to sort a struct based on 2 fields in C?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort, ranking, bubble-sort

I have a struct used in a Hangman game where the user gets points based on the number of incorrect attempts.

My question is how to rank them, taking into account both the points (pontos) and the number of games (n_jogos).

So for example:

- A user that has 10 points and only played once should come before a user that has 15 points that played 2 games.

So far I've tried to:

- implement qsort(), but since I don't really understand it, I wasn't able to get it to work.
- implement a bubble sort, which worked in sorting by number of games, but not in sorting by both number of games and points.

Any help would be very apreciated, thank you.

Comment: Figure out how to use `qsort()`, please don't write yet another [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) implementation. Do you have code from your `qsort()` attempt? That's something we can build on. This code is not.

Comment: Also consider using dynamically allocated strings like `char*` instead of arbitrary-length strings like `char[50]`. Copying these can be very painful and they're liable to suffer from catastrophic buffer overflow bugs.

Comment: You have first  to define a criteria for sorting the players. You have two numbers. For example, the number of points per game.

Comment: You would call `qsort` with `qsort(utilizador, n_jogadores, sizeof *utilizador, MyComparisonFunction)`. Declare that function as `int MyComparisonFunction(const void *a, const void *b)`. Inside the function, make pointers to your structure with `Utilizador *A = a, *B = b;`. Then compute a “score” for sorting with `double Ascore = computations from A;` and `double Bscore = computations from B;`. Then finish the routine with `if (Ascore < Bscore) return -1; else if (Ascore == Bscore) return 0; else return 1;`. A score might be `double Ascore = (double) A->pontos / A->n_jogos;`.

Answer (score 3):

> A user that has 10 points and only played once should come before a user that has 15 points that played 2 games.

Is it the case, then, that you want to rank by number of games first, and then by points?  I'll assume Yes, but if not, then you have to decide what the ordering criteria are. Here's a function you could pass to **qsort**(3).  Season to taste.

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[50], password[50];
    int pontos, n_jogos;
} Utilizador;

int cmp ( const void *A, const void *B ) {
    const Utilizador *a=A, *b=B;

    if( a->jogos == b->jogos) {
        if( a->pontos == b-pontos ) return 0;
        return a->pontos < b-pontos? -1 : 1;
    }
    return  a->jogos < b->jogos? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a rank:

```
double userRank = (double)pontos / (double)n_jogos;
```

Then just adjust the ranking system by weighting those two variables with multipliers.

Sort by user rank.